# Data validation in workflow services

Tags: wcf, validation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I want to validate the data coming to all receive activities in a single point (in a workflow service). I guess custom tracking should  not be used in this case for "validation in workflow" option as it will not guarantee that execution of receive will be prevented.

The other option is WCF boundary but using WCF parameter inspector is not simple enough I think (message deserialization etc).

What would be the optimum point for data validation?